# PyQt5: Got AttributeError while using QObject and QThread

Tags: python, multithreading, qthread, qobject, pyqt5

I got a problem while I was developing a programme that can retrieve contains from different sites at the same time (now is basically retrieving definition of a word from two or more online dictionaries).

I used QObject and QThread to develop my programme. Everything went fine at first, but when I tried to search for and retrieve contains of another word again, I got 2 AttributeError.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from gui import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal

class Searcher(QObject):
    signalUpdate=pyqtSignal(str, str)

    def __init__(self, dictionary, word):
        super(Searcher, self).__init__()
        self.dictionary=dictionary
        self.word=word
    def run(self):
        self.signalUpdate.emit(self.dictionary, self.word)      

class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow, QObject):
    signalSearch=pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.dictList=['Yahoo dictionary', 'Webster dictionary']
        self.searchThreads=[QThread(), QThread()]


    def click(self):
        word=self.lineEdit.text()
        self.searchers=[]

        for dictionary in self.dictList:
            self.searchers.append(Searcher(dictionary, word))

        for index , searcher in enumerate(self.searchers):
            searcher.signalUpdate.connect(self.updateGUI)
            searcher.moveToThread(self.searchThreads[index])
            self.searchThreads[index].start()
            self.signalSearch.connect(searcher.run)

        self.signalSearch.emit()

    def updateGUI(self, dictionary, word):
        print(dictionary+'['+word+']')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyMainWindow()
    myapp.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I don't know how to deal with this problem. Does anyone know how to get rid of it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\workspace\online-dictionary\main.py", line 22, in run
File "C:\workspace\online-dictionary\main.py", line 22, in run
self.signalUpdate.emit(self.dictionary, self.word)      
self.signalUpdate.emit(self.dictionary, self.word)      
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'signalUpdate'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'signalUpdate'
```

Comment: Can you please provide the full traceback?

Comment: I've added the traceback on the post. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by deleting the list of searcher objects every time a search is done, which is unnecessary.

You only need to create the searcher objects once, and then make requests to them by emitting `signalSearch` with the required word.

So the searcher class would look like this:

```
class Searcher(QObject):
    signalUpdate = pyqtSignal(str, str)

    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        super(Searcher, self).__init__()
        self.dictionary = dictionary

    # word is sent by signalSearch
    def run(self, word):
        self.signalUpdate.emit(self.dictionary, word)
```

and the main window class would look like this:

```
class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    signalSearch = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.dictList = ['Yahoo dictionary', 'Webster dictionary']
        self.searchThreads = []
        self.searchers = []
        # create all the threads and searchers once
        for dictionary in self.dictList:
            thread = QThread(self)
            self.searchThreads.append(thread)
            searcher = Searcher(dictionary)
            self.searchers.append(searcher)
            searcher.signalUpdate.connect(self.updateGUI)
            self.signalSearch.connect(searcher.run)
            searcher.moveToThread(thread)
            thread.start()

    def click(self):
        # send a new word to the searchers
        self.signalSearch.emit(self.lineEdit.text())

    def updateGUI(self, dictionary, word):
        print(dictionary+'['+word+']')
```